# DataGridView.DataSource returns empty DataTable when called from other form

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have `DataGridView` named dGV.

Firstly I set its `DataSource`using an empty `DataTable` which has 300 rows and 50 columns so users can input their data in the `DataGridView`.

When I tried to call the `dGV` from other form after inputing the data it always returned that empty `DataTable`. Here's my code :

MainForm :

```
public MainForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dGV.DataSource = GetTable();
}

public DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for(int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("V"+i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 301; i++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add();
    }     
    return table;
}

public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = dGV.DataSource as DataTable;
    return dt;
}
```

Form2 :

```
private void NDokButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    DataTable dt = mf.GetData();
    var n = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
    String a = n.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

It shows an empty MessageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your second form creates an entirely new form, one in which the data grid is never populated.

Instead of creating a new format you need to pass a reference to the first for or its data grid to accomplish what you want.

Remember that new means new. Just because you create a new instance of an object does not mean that it will have anything to do with the first object  (except for statics which would be a bad idea here).

Create a public property of type For in your 2nd form and set the value when you're creating the 2nd form, which I assume is happening in the first form. You will basically do something like this:

```
secondForm.RefToFirst = this;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance of `MainForm` when you click the button.  That will fill the `DataGridView` with a bunch of empty data.  Then you grab an empty cell and display it in a text box.

Pass a reference to the existing `MainForm` to the second form.

```
private void NDokButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You're creating a new main form here.  You need an instance of the existing form.
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    DataTable dt = mf.GetData();
    var n = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
    String a = n.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added new function in the `Form2`

```
 public DataTable dat = new DataTable();
 public DataTable GetFromMainForm(DataTable dt) {
            this.dat = dt;
            return dat;
        }

        private DataTable GetFromMainForm() {
            return dat;
        }


private void NDokButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetFromMainForm();
            var n = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
            String a = n.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(a);

        }
```

In the `MainForm`i pass the `DataTable` to `Form2`

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.GetFromMainForm(dt);
```